# Best approach to manage different screen size in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to know how can i manage my view to look like decent as i want on different screen size on android. If i arrange item for 4 inch screen than it get overlapped on 3.5 inch screen and it scatters on tablet screen size.
So please share your secrete to manage different screen size and orientation.
Thank you so much.

Here is XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="247dp"
    android:layout_height="183dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/headphone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:text=" Play Now"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:text="Web"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:src="@drawable/web" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="No Internet Avaliable " />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="198dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="Select Channel " />
```

Comment: if you share your screen it will easy to identify your issues and there is nothing secrete to do for all screen sizes.

Comment: can you please share your xml file code ?

Comment: Hello madam, I am new to this fourm so i dont know how to post image with post..but i can explain you what item i have in my view. there is List view having 5 items , imageview with width=fill_parent, 2 buttons ? shrelock actionbar with menu items..if i organise items according to 4 inch display and if install that app into 3.5 inch phone than item get overlapped..i want it to be scrollable when screen size is small..

Comment: xml is added in main question

Comment: @SwapAndroid you can upload image here : http://imgur.com/ . Then paste the URL here for reference

Comment: Ok wait please
[IMG]http://i.imgur.com/nqPvA.png[/IMG]

Comment: its ok with portrait mode [IMG]http://i.imgur.com/BdWVx.png[/IMG] but i cant able to resize image of play now and web and i cant be able to arrange onto location as where i want..

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try **Linear Layout**, giving **weight** to the child elements you use in your layout. Other then that you have to create different layout for **l/m/h dpi** set.

Comment: I tried that but 3.5 and 4 inch both device got access to Medium screen size layout..3.5 to 3 inch automatically access to medium xml file and screen size which is less than 3 inch got access to small xml file..